# Help: jQuery UI resizable doesn't work properly!

Tags: jquery, user-interface, resizable

The jQuery UI Demo for the resizable provides a page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/textarea.html

And I followed that to make a similar page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<style>
.ui-resizable-se {
bottom: 17px;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({
handles: "se"
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo">
<textarea id="resizable" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But there's no handle image(the one in the bottom right) in my page! I compared my code with the sample. Actually, they're nearly the same except the header "including" js and css files. Am I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You must include jquery.ui.core.js (and possibly other JS files).

Comment: But I think I downloaded all the components of jQuery UI 1.8.13, just clicking the right most 'download' button of page "http://jqueryui.com/download" with all components selected.

Comment: Did you check in Firebug (Net panel) if the files are downloaded? You could have the wrong path... Also, you could try inclucing all the files manually (non-minified and non-bundled) to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

inside the "**jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css**" file delete this "**background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=);**" from line **305** and it will work fine :)

Comment: It does appear, but the location seems incorrect: just a little space above where it should be. And in IE9, it resides on the scroll bar:(

Comment: sorry, i didn't get you answer. What doesn't appear?